# function registering after document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to understand how the browser works if it has 2 document.ready functions within it.

Sample code: Here printtest() module has a alert statement within my first document.ready function and its been called below but I don't see any action..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function printtest(){
       alert('Hi')
    }


})

$(document).ready(function(){

    printtest()


})


http://jsfiddle.net/7FuLc/1/
```

Since it has 2 document.ready function, how does the browser registers this function?

Comment: this has nothing to do with the document ready function specifically, you simply defined a function in one place, then tried to use it in another where it isn't defined.

Comment: There's rarely any reason to wait to *define* a function until the document is ready unless you're doing it to avoid making the function global.

Answer (score 0):

That code will not work because because javascript function creates a new scope variable every time it is declared. See the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function printtest(){
       alert('Hi')
    }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    printtest() // ReferenceError, printtest undefined
})
```

compare this to

```
function printtest(){
    alert('Hi')
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    printtest() // alerts 'Hi'
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    printtest() // alerts 'Hi'
})
```

This way, both `$(document).ready(function(){})` understand what `printtest` is.

---

To solve your problem, here is the modified code,

```
var printtest;

$(document).ready(function(){
    printtest = function (){
       alert('Hi')
    }
})

$(document).ready(function(){
    printtest(); // alerts 'Hi'
})
```

**Now this will work** the way you intend it to be because you declare the variable outside the function. This is due to `closure` (`closure` is inner javascript function, meaning that any outside variable can be accessed inside the inner javascript function).

**In conclusion**, if you want a function that is accessible across different functions, declare it outside so that any other closure will be able to access it.